# Every ordered space has an ordered compactification.

Tags: general-topology

**Prove that every ordered space has an ordered compactification.**

This is a homework question and i am following Munkres' Topology.
I am quite new to the idea about the compactification of a space.
How can we show its existence?

How can i proceed, any idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Are you familiar with the construction of the reals from the rationals using Dedekind cuts? That’s the idea that you want here: use Dedekind cuts to form the Dedekind completion of the space. (By the way, did you mean *Munkres*? It’s definitely in Willard.)

Answer (score 0):

The statement you are trying to prove is false. As per [this paper](http://people.wku.edu/tom.richmond/Papers/UNISA.pdf):

> an ordered space has an ordered compactification if and only if it is *completely regularly ordered*.

(see the top of page 2, and the book "Topology and Order" by Nachbin cited therein.)

Comment: By *ordered space* the OP means a linearly ordered set with the order topology, and in that context the statement is true. Nachbin’s ordered spaces are a wider class: his orders need only be partial orders.

Comment: But i can see this problem in Willard's General Topology. Is this problem suggesting something else apart from completely regularity of the space?

Comment: @User101: Ignore **pre-kidney**’s answer; it’s simply not relevant to your problem.